# Using scapy through RPyC

Tags: python, scapy, rpyc

I need to use scapy on remote server to dump traffic like this

```
sniff(filter='icmp', iface='eth1', timeout=5)
```

To connect to remote server I'm using RPyC.

```
conn = rpyc.classic.connect(HOST_IP)
```

but I can not understand how to use scapy on remote server. 
How to call sniff function on remote server through RPyC?

The question may be considered wider - how to import module on remote machine and use its functions?

Comment: Perhaps you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32406949/2096752

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be sniffing with an `icmp` filter. You'll need to filter for `tcp` to get RPyC connections, which go over TCP.